# Terraform conditional - assert resource is defined depending on if a variable is x or y

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

I have an Elastic Beanstalk resource that contains several optional settings.  One of these is a queue depending on whether the `tier` of the EB is `worker` or not.

The template that calls this module has a value `worker`.

What I'd like to do is something that achieves the following:
`if tier == worker; assert queue != null`

I've looked at the count meta believing this may be the correct path but I cannot piece it together.

My current iteration is this but I feel it's too convoluted and there is a better approach(and it doesn't work):

```
/eb template
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
  name                   = var.name
  application            = var.application_name
  tier                   = var.tier
  solution_stack_name    = var.solution_stack_name

  //Worker setting
  setting {
    //count     = var.is_worker_tier ? 1 : 0
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd"
    name      = var.worker_queue_name
    value     = var.queue //only set if worker.
  }
}

//vars
variable "is_worker_tier" {
  type = boolean
  default = false
  description = "when true will create the sqs queue optional setting"
}

//where the module is called
module "test_beanstalk_3" {
  tier = "Worker"
  queue = "myQueue"
///
}
```

as an extension of this, I'd like to enforce that the queue name and url is set.
For example, I have:

```
variable "worker_queue_name" {
  type = string
  default = "WorkerQueueURL"
  description = "name of the worker queue, replace with arn if able to."
}

variable "queue" {
  type = string
  default = ""
  description = "List of application subnet ids"
}
```

Currently, these can be empty strings when creating a worker which I'd really like to update so that `if worker; var.queue != ""

Comment: Can you provide actually valid TF code? What you provided is not a valid TF code and it will never work. What is `}(and it` or `setting`?

Comment: Hey @Marcin that block at the end is a typo from my post, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
  name                   = var.name
  application            = var.application_name
  tier                   = var.tier
  solution_stack_name    = var.solution_stack_name

  //Worker setting
  dynamic "setting"{
    for_each = var.tier == "Worker" ? [1] : [] 
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd"
      name      = var.worker_queue_name
      value     = var.queue //only set if worker.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, that's great.  Annoyingly I already have a dynamic block in place but hadn't considered it for this purpose :( 

Can I ask is the 'is_worker_tier' a sensible option?  would it be better or more feasible to have this check on the value of tier instead and remove that extra boolean?

Comment: @steve No problem. You need to have some condition, but you can just use `var.tier`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Marcin.  There is one final component of this you may be able to help with and that's asserting that the queue name is not "" when worker tier is set.  I've updated the question if you have a moment at all to take a look

Comment: @steve Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe a new question with new code would be more clearer.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll create another question as that may be easier.  I'm just trying to enforce that the worker queue value is not left as an empty string when worker is the tier.  Though I'm not sure how that would translate in terraform.  
In the updated question when I have 'queue=myQueue' I'd like to make sure that happens when the tier is worker rather than using the default value of empty string.